# com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.1.1,17.1.1]], but resolves to 19.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

Recently my ionic project build stuck below this issue

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.1.1,17.1.1]], but resolves to 19.0.0
```

This is not the first time I came across this issue whenevr google update the firebase version I always stuck with similar kind of issue. I googled it every time and some how find the solution. but this time its too difficult to get rid of this.

any one has any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1081

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue after changing firebase-message library version issue resolved.

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating google services to latest version in your apps Top-level build file. As of now latest version is as below:-

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: is there any permanent solution bcz this comes everytime and I don't want any manual change in android code

Comment: For Ionic your changes to android project will remain until you delete and recreate the android project. Did the above solution worked for you?